# Compare one row of a table to every rows of a second table

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am trying to retrieve the number of days between a random date and the next known date for a holiday. Let's say my first table looks like this :

```
date | is_holiday | zone   
9/11/18 | 0 | A    
22/12/18 | 1 | A
```

and my holidays table looks like this

```
start_date | end_date | zone    
20/12/18 | 04/01/18 | A    
21/12/18 | 04/01/18 | B
...
```

I want to be able to know how many days are between an entry that is not a holiday in the first table and the next holiday date.

I have tried to get the next row with a later date in a join clause but the join isn't the tool for this task. I also have tried grouping by date and comparing the date with the next row but I can have multiple entries with the same date in the first table so it doesn't work.

This is the join clause I have tried :

```
SELECT mai.*, vac.start_date, datediff(vac.start_date, mai.date)
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM MAIN
      WHERE is_holiday = 0
     ) mai LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT start_date, zone
      FROM VACATIONS_UPDATED
      ORDER BY start_date
     ) vac 
     ON mai.date < vac.start_date AND mai.zone = vac.zone
```

I expect to get a table looking like this :

```
date | is_holiday | zone | next_holiday    
9/11/18 | 0 | A | 11    
22/12/18 | 1 | A | 0
```

Any lead on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It might get messy to do it in SQL but if in case you are open to doing it from code, here is what it should look like. You basically need a *crossJoin*

```
Dataset<Row> table1 = <readData>
Dataset<Row> holidays = <readData>

//then cache the small table to get the best performance

table1.crossJoin( holidays ).filter("table1.zone == holidays.zone AND table1.date < holidays.start_date").select( "table1.*", "holidays.start_date").withColumn("nextHoliday", *calc diff*)
```

In scenarios where one row from *table1* matches multiple *holidays*, then you can add an id column to *table1* and then group the *crossJoin*.

```
// add unique id to the rows
table1 = table1.withColumn("id", functions.monotonically_increasing_id() )
```

Some details on crossJoins:
http://kirillpavlov.com/blog/2016/04/23/beyond-traditional-join-with-apache-spark/